# in C#, there are two threads when I call BeginXXX

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I know something about the IOCP, but I'm a little confused with APM.

```
static FileStream fs;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    fs = new FileStream(@"c:\bigfile.txt", FileMode.Open);
    var buffer = new byte[10000000];
    IAsyncResult asyncResult = fs.BeginRead(buffer, 0, 10000000, OnCompletedRead, null);
    Console.WriteLine("async...");
    int bytesRead = fs.EndRead(asyncResult);
    Console.WriteLine("async... over");
}

static void OnCompletedRead(IAsyncResult ar)
{
       Console.WriteLine("finished");
}
```

I wonder, is the read action executed by an IO thread asynchronously? Or a worker thread in a thread pool?

And the callback function `OnCompletedRead`, is it also executed by an IO thread in CLR thread pool?

Are these two threads the same one? If not, there are two threads generated, one executes the read action and another does the callback.

Comment: You should not call `EndReceive` inside `Main`. You should instead call it in `OnCompleteRead` otherwise you are not getting any of the benefits of async calls.

Comment: I'd also recommend reading http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: I read that blog. So there is no thread to process the read action. But the callback executes on the IO thread, am I right?

Comment: @roast_soul close, the OS uses a IO (threadpool) thread to signal that the data is ready. What happens after that signal is raised is a "implementation detail", it could run the callback on the [completion port pool, the worker pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads(v=vs.110).aspx), or by queuing it on a Synchronization Context that was associated with the class when the async operation started ([System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject(v=vs.110).aspx) is a good example of this)

Comment: You probably see the IOCP completion thread that calls your OnCompletedRead() method.  And the "wait thread", it takes care of the IOCP plumbing.  So yes, two threads.  Key to the wait thread is that it handles *any* pending IOCP request, it starts to pay off when you have multiple BeginXxxx calls in flight.  Typically only useful for sockets.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't use an AsyncCallback argument with BeginRead then there is only one thread that runs code in your program. This uses IO completion ports to  signal when the IO is complete by running a small amount of code on a thread in the IO thread pool to update the status of the operation as being complete. When you call EndRead it will block the current thread until the IO operation is complete. It is asynchronous in that when you start the read operation the current thread does not need to do anything other than wait for the IO hardware to perform the read operation, so you can do other things in the meantime and then decide when you want to stop and wait for the IO to finish.

If you do pass in an AsyncCallback then when the IO operation is complete it will execute a small amount of code on an IO thread pool thread which will trigger your callback method to be executed on a thread from the .NET thread pool.

Comment: you mean the callback function is exectued by main thread? really? I don't think so.

Comment: @roast_soul it depends on the implementation of `BeginXxxxx` some methods will capture the synchronization context and run the call back on the thread in the context, others will use a threadpool thread to run on when the IO completion port signals the data is ready. It is not defined in the [APM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) unlike async/await which does always check the `SynchronizationContext` unless you tell it not to with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Also you could try writing the current thread's managed thread id to console from the main method and from your callback and see what it says.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, mclaassen is right about the nature of IO bound work, IOCP and the APM. When `BeginRead` executes, it does so asynchronously all the way down to kernel mode. But, there is one caveat specifically in your example that he didn't mention in his answer.

In your example, you use the `FileStream` class. One **important** thing to note is that if you dont use the `FileStream` overload that accepts a `useAsync` boolean, when you invoke a `BeginWrite` / `EndWrite` operation, it will **queue work on a new `ThreadPool` thread**.

This is the proper overload:

```
public FileStream(
    string path,
    FileMode mode,
    FileAccess access,
    FileShare share,
    int bufferSize,
    bool useAsync
)
```

From MSDN:

> **useAsync:**
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> Specifies whether to use asynchronous
> I/O or synchronous I/O. However, note that the underlying operating
> system might not support asynchronous I/O, so when specifying true,
> the handle might be opened synchronously depending on the platform.
> When opened asynchronously, the BeginRead and BeginWrite methods
> perform better on large reads or writes, but they might be much slower
> for small reads or writes. If the application is designed to take
> advantage of asynchronous I/O, set the useAsync parameter to true.
> Using asynchronous I/O correctly can speed up applications by as much
> as a factor of 10, but using it without redesigning the application
> for asynchronous I/O can decrease performance by as much as a factor
> of 10.

You have to make sure each specific method implementing the APM pattern truly uses true asynchronous work all the way down.